# how to block all images of website in uiwebview ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

- how to block all images in UIWebview like as if you are open
  yahoo.com in this website all image content should be block mens user
  can not see image.

  thanks.

Comment: below link desribe hot to block image in uiwebview

Click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516018/how-to-block-load-image-in-uiwebview-ios)

Comment: @Ankit Kargathra Hello Bro i have same requirement if you solve this please help me. How to block image?

Answer (score 0):

You could run or install some JavaScript which traverses the DOM and hides all images. Or add CSS for image tags to hide them. Or deny any image URL request in the web view delegate. There are a number of possible solutions depending on how the images are loaded and how you can tell what an image actually is.

Comment: Hello Bro if you know how to block image please give me some line of code how to block it in uiwebview.